# unable to use shape predictor file in python

Tags: python, deserialization, raspberry-pi3, dlib

I have been working on python for emotion detection. I installed dlib library for python on my Rpi but whenever i try to use my shape_predictor file with extension ".dat" it gives out this error:

```
error :    predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(predictor_path)
RuntimeError: Error deserializing a floating point number.
   while deserializing a dlib::matrix
   while deserializing object of type std::vector
   while deserializing object of type std::vector
   while deserializing object of type std::vector
```

i have no idea what deserializing means and why im facing this!i m a newbie to python! ned help

Comment: Renaming archive will not work. Try decompressing file before usage

Comment: Thanks Evgeniy it worked, it was working without decompressing on my windows  that's why i couldn't figure it out. I decompressed it usind Pi's extractor tool. Thanks